# Uploading an image file from Ctr+V event (javascript)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, canvas, base64, blob

I am trying to use the technique shown here: http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/ to capture an image the user pastes onto the webpage. This is compatible with Chrome and Firefox.

Everything works well. The image data is supposed to be stored in `pastedImage.src`. I am able to display the image on the page (into an img element, or draw it on a canvas).

However, what gets stored in `pastedImage.src` differs in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox stores the actual image, in a base64 encoded data URL, which I can parse and upload; Chrome stores a temp URL in the form http://[domain]/[string] that does point to the image. Please see this here: http://test.vapenerd.com/paste.html

I can't really figure out how to get the actual image data from that - I tried to a `FileReader()` on it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Right now my workaround is to draw the image into a canvas and then get it using the `toDataURL()` method which returns a base64 encoded data URL.

I am sorry, I am not a web developer,  hope this is not too confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read it as a data uri

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
    createImage(event.target.result);
}; // data url!
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6Up6/2/)

Comment: Darn... Now I feel dumb. That's what I tried, but must have made some syntax error and then gave it up... THANK YOU!